# Facebook - Create App Error

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create an App via the Facebook Developer Console.  Once logged in, I click the Create App button, I fill out the Display Name, Contact Email and choose the Category, finally clicking Create App ID.

At that point I get the error message seen below.  I'm not sure WHAT other account I can use to sign in to make this work.  What does this message mean?  What am I supposed to do in order to create a new app?

[image]

After looking through Facebook's support forum, it was their recommendation that I post to Stackoverflow.com and tag the question with facebook.com, so I apologize for the general question, but they told me to ;)

Thank you!!

Comment: Are you logged in as a page? Or a work account? Have you verified your account?

Comment: I think I'm logged in as a normal account.  How could I check this?

Comment: Do you have a personal Facebook user account? If not, go create one. And then, go to the developer section, and sign up as a developer.

Comment: @CBroe - that's all fine, and I can do that, but I need to post from a website to the page that I log in with when I get the error message in my question.  Can I link the two somehow?

Comment: Posting to a page as the page is done by using a page access token for the request. That has nothing to do with the creation of the app, which you do using your user account.